# How to manually calculate concordance for a coxPH model

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards, concordance

I am struggling to work out how the concordance statistic of a coxPH model is derived.

I have built a coxPH model on a small dataset (4 observations). The resultant model is given below:

```
Call:

coxph(formula = Surv(time, bad) ~ input, data = data, method = "breslow")
n= 4, number of events= 3 

         coef     exp(coef) se(coef)      z      Pr(>|z|)
input -0.3466    0.7071       1.4355    -0.241    0.809

        exp(coef)    exp(-coef)    lower .95    upper .95
input    0.7071      1.414         0.04242       11.79

Concordance= 0.6  (se = 0.245 )
Rsquare= 0.014   (max possible= 0.711 )
Likelihood ratio test= 0.06  on 1 df,   p=0.8096
Wald test            = 0.06  on 1 df,   p=0.8092
Score (logrank) test = 0.06  on 1 df,   p=0.8084
```

The concordance for this coxPH model is 0.6. However, i am really struggling to work out how this is calculated. I have read that concordance involves pairs of observations, their time to event, and their cox prediction but i cannot work out how the final concordance value is calculated.

Below is a summary of the dataset that was used, along with the cox prediction (lp) for each observation:

```
 Observation    time    bad    cox prediction 
 1              1       1      0.1732
 2              2       1     -0.1732
 3              3       0     -0.1732
 4              4       1      0.1732
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated